# AttributeError( AttributeError: Generic detail view 'class' must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I really need some help here, please.

I think my code is right but when i call python manage-py runserver an error appears.

• models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    product_id = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("api:detail", kwargs={"product_id": self.product_id})
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import Product


class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product


class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import ProductListView, ProductDetailView


app_name = "api"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('<slug:product_id>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

error log

> in get_object raise AttributeError( AttributeError: Generic detail
> view ProductDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a
> slug in the URLconf.

Answer (score 1):

Since your model has the slug field named differently you would need to set a few class attributes in your view namely `slug_url_kwarg` and `slug_field`:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    slug_url_kwarg = 'product_id'
    slug_field = 'product_id'
```

`DetailView` has [`SingleObjectMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjectmixin) as one of it's ancestors which handles getting the object and has these attributes.